# SignalR Call Method

Tags: c#, signalr

Made a simple winforms app using hubs.
I can get the following line of code to display my message, this works fine:

```
 chat.On<ChatMessage>("AddMessage", (message) => this.Invoke((Action) (() => lblMessage.Text = message.Msg
                    )));
```

However if I try to call a method it does not fire

```
chat.On<ChatMessage>("AddMessage", (message) => this.Invoke((Action) (() => ShowForm(message))));

 private void ShowForm(dynamic r)
    {

        lblMessage.Text = r.Message;
        this.Show();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the server code. Check whether model is the same on server and client

Comment: Is the client trying to connect using web sockets? Had problems with this myself between a windows service and an OWIN hosted hub. Had to fallback to server sent events.

Comment: Isn't `Show()` blocking? If it is you basically deadlocked yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Making it `async` worked

```
private async void ShowForm(string r)
{
    lblMessage.Text = r;
    this.Show();
}
```